# ulong to hex conversion clarification

Tags: c#, unicode, hex, type-conversion, ulong

I have a reference program which I got online. In that variable `data64` is defined as `ulong` type. Which they're converting to unicode and displaying in a textbox like this:

`TextBox1.AppendText = Rxmsg.data64.ToString("X");`

The actual value of `data64` is "12288092688749907974".
While it displays in textbox the value is "AA88133200035006". I thought it's a simple decimal to hex conversion. So I converted the `data64` value to hex but I was wrong. Can anyone please clarify me how the above conversion was made? It's related to one of my projects. It would be very useful for me to proceed further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

reason is the Endianness of the display

> IsLittleEndian Yes: 06-50-03-00-32-13-88-AA
>
> IsLittleEndian No: AA-88-13-32-00-03-50-06

[fiddle demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/t0aklk) and [wikipedia link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness)

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var value = 12288092688749907974u;
            var bytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(value);

            Console.Write(BitConverter.IsLittleEndian ? "IsLittleEndian Yes" : "IsLittleEndian No");
            Console.WriteLine(" Value " + BitConverter.ToString(bytes));

            Array.Reverse(bytes);
            Console.Write(BitConverter.IsLittleEndian ? "IsLittleEndian No" : "IsLittleEndian Yes");
            Console.WriteLine(" Value " + BitConverter.ToString(bytes));

            Console.Read();
        }
    }
}
```